# Icons do not show up in Informatica Mapping Designer

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am new to Informatica and I am trying to learn it bit by bit.Currently I am able to enable the repository services but nothing works after I get connected. As in the transformation icons do not get highlighted when I open the mapping designer. Please find the attached screen-shot. Let me know if any questions. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: SOrry.I added the screen-shot now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You opened the *Mapping Designer* and connected to a folder but **there is no mapping loaded** - create a new mapping or open an existing one and transformations toolbar will become active.

Answer (score 0):

You should have required permission to create source, target, mappings, transformations etc. Icons will be enables only when you have sufficient permission.

Answer (score -1):

Can think of two possibilities,

1. you have disabled the toolbar...try right clicking in the toolbar area, and switch it on...
2. you might not have "Opened" the folder.  Clicking the plus sign around the folder is not the same as right click -> open for a folder.  Unless you open the folder, the areas for source analyzer etc, dont really open up for you..